# VS 2013 Express, working with Unity configuraion, no IntelliSense support

Tags: visual-studio-2013, unity-container, intellisense

How to enable IntelliSense support for Unity configuration?

I did take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507436(v=pandp.30).aspx and acted accordingly, but with no luck.

Why VS does not pick up http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity for xml?

Comment: Downloaded https://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#source/UnityConfiguration30.xsd and added to project. Works now. I wonder however, how to achieve the same with installation from NuGet.. .

Comment: What about not using XML at all? XML based DI configuration is brittle, error prone and always provides a subset of what you can achieve with code based configuration. General consensus is to use code based configuration as much as possible and only fall back to file based configuration for the parts of the configuration that really need to be customizable after deployment. Even for those few lines that do need to be configurable, it’s a bad idea to require the fully qualified type name in a configuration file. A configuration switch (true/false or simple enum) is more than enough.

Comment: I am using Unity in order to define sequence for some execution. I will have multiple steps and multiple configurations where steps in sequence will vary. So, I can setup new sequences without rebuilding. I am using console application. I could use Form based approach to define step order, but that would be redundant atm. But thanks any way!